# Return contents of cells in range if not blank

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to return the contents of a range of cells if any of the cells are not blank. Hopefully this will result in one or more names in cell where my formula is. I cannot find the answer and I know this should be easy. Any help is appreciated. Here is my formula: =IF(ISBLANK(B2:B11)=FALSE,(B2:B11),"")

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge this is not possible to do in one cell.

Comment: How would I do it if I just wanted to know if one cell contained a name?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this actually interested me since I wasn't sure if it was possible so I found the following link. https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/    The instructions here are pretty good and should solve what you want.